# How to set a signal high X-time before rising edge of clock cycle?

Tags: verilog, clock, register-transfer-level

I have a signal that checks if the data is available in memory block and does some computation/logic (Which is irrelevant).

I want a signal called "START_SIG" to go high X-time (nanoseconds) before the first rising edge of the clock cycle that is at 10 MHz Frequency. This only goes high if it detects there is data available and does further computation as needed.

Now, how can this be done? Also, I cannot set a delay since this must be RTL Verilog. Therefore, it must be synthensizable on an FPGA (Artix7 Series).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect an XY problem, if start sig is produced by logic in the same clock domain as your processing then timing will likely be met without any work on your part (10MHz is dead slow in FPGA terms), but if you really needed to do something like this there are a few ways (But seriously you are doing it wrong!).
FPGA logic is usually synchronous to one or more clocks,generally needing vernier control within a clock period is a sign of doing it wrong.

Use a {PLL/MCM/Whatever} to generate two clocks, one dead slow at 10Mhz, and something much faster, then count the fast one from the previous edge of the 10MHz clock to get your timing.

Use an MCMPLL or such (platform dependent) to generate two 10Mhz clocks with a small phase shift, then gate one of em.

Use a long line of inverter pairs (attribute KEEP (VHDL But verilog will have something similar) will be your friend), calibrate against your known clock periodically (it will drift with temperature, day of the week and sign of the zodiac), this is neat for things like time to digital converters, possibly combined with option two for fine trimming. Shades of ring oscs about this one, but whatever works.

Comment: Hi Dan, typo. Was a 1Mhz Signal. Anyways, I did not realize that. So if the start_sig is dependent on other signals, then I should not be concerned about the exact time it starts ? That does make sense though, just re-claryifing this again so we agree on the same point. Since other data is dependent on start_sig, start_sig will only start once it receives that data.

Comment: Providing all your logic is synchronous to that clock (1MHz is VERY slow for FPGA doings) it will likely just work, but note that external IO usually needs to be synchronized to the clock by a register pair, and that crossing clock domains has issues all of its own. A migrate to Electrical Engineering is suggested, you will likely get better answers there.